# How to include boost.js in Highchart in Angular 5 application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have installed Highcharts in my Angular 5 application by npm. I want my high chart to have boost. I have tried including the boost.js using 'allowJs' in tsconfig file and imported that to my component. Highchart works fine ,however the boost does not seem to work along with Highchart. The error throws as below from boost.js.

```
scripts.bundle.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at scripts.bundle.js:15
```

---

What is the correct way to have boost in Highchart.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sad there is no answer here